# jQuery Cycle - What's wrong with this jquery script?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, numbers, jquery-animate, cycle

I am using the jquery cycle plugin to do a slideshow. I have 5 photos sliding but only showing 3 thumbnail pagers at a time. I wanted that when it slides to the 4th photo, the thumbnails on a bottom changes so it shows the 4th and 5th thumbnails.

I have a "Next" and "Prev" button on the page, when click on "Next" it'll display the 4th and 5th thumbnails, click "Prev" to go back to the 1st-3rd thumbnail. So basically, i want the div that contains the thumbnail to animate left automatically when it slides to the 4th photo as if you clicked on the "Next" button. But i have no idea why it isnt working....

Here's the scrip that start the slide and return the number of the current slide:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#slideshow').cycle({           
        fx:     'turnDown',
        speed:  'fast',
        pager:  '#nav',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
            // return sel string for existing anchor
            return '#nav li:eq(' + (idx) + ') a';
        } ,
    after: function (curr, next, opts) {
   var number = (opts.currSlide + 1);
$('#caption1').html(number);
},  
    });
});
</script>
```

Here's the code that controls the "Next" and "Prev" button

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#next_control').click(function() {
        var c = $('#nav_content');
        var pos = c.position();
        var w = c.width();
        var status = w + pos.left;
        var dif = w - 190;
        var x = w + dif;
        if (status > 190) {
            c.stop().animate({
                left: pos.left - 180
            }, 500);
        };
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#prev_control').click(function() {
        var c = $('#nav_content');
        var pos = c.position();
        if (pos.left < 0) {
            c.stop().animate({
                left: pos.left + 180
            }, 500)
        };
    });
});
```

**Finally**, here's the code that I thought would run the same effect as clicking on the "Next" button when the slideshow slides to the 4th photo. But it's not working for some reason....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if(number = 4){
            $('#nav_content').stop().animate({left: pos.left - 180},500);
            }              
                           });
</script>
```

Any idea..? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `number == 4` in your last code block?  Also, you're referencing a locally scoped variable in another function, which isn't going to work.

Comment: Hi Danalog, you mean I can't use the variable "number" in functions other than cycle? Do yo know how to make it work..? thx

Comment: You need to either make it a global variable (yuck) or pull it back out of your DOM somehow.  Since it looks like you're setting it in `$('#caption1').html(number);`, perhaps you could pull it back out of the `#caption1` element?

Comment: Ah..can't get it to work, I'm new to coding actually, this is frustrating :(  I used `var z = $('#caption1').html();` as a new variable, this should be the number of the currently displayed slide. Then I used `if(z = 4){$('#nav_content').stop().animate({left: pos.left - 180},500);}` what's wrong with it?

Comment: `z = 4` assigns the value of 4 to z.  `z == 4` tests if z is equal to 4.  I'm not 100% sure about the rest of your jQuery stuff you're doing there, but I can see that logic problem at least.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what's wrong finally...i didn't define the variable "pos" in the last code block.
Solved the problem now. Thanks for the help Danalog!

Comment: Glad I was able to help!  I should have noticed that pos wasn't defined when number wasn't defined, sorry!